# In Django models, how does the foreign key field know which field to match with in the other model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I understand what Foreign Keys do but I'm having trouble understanding why this is working in Django.

I have the Project model in 'app1/models.py' file. This model has a ForeignKey named 'owner' that links to the Profile model in my 'app2/models.py' file.

**How does the 'owner' field in the Project model know it should be linking to the 'user' field in the Profile model if I'm only passing the model name to the 'owner' field?** I feel like I should be passing the Profile.field or something like this in the Project model:

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile.user, null=True, blank=True ... )
```

Full model code from Dennis Ivy's tutorial:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
            null=True, blank=True, upload_to='profiles/', default='profiles/user-default.png')
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, 
                            primary_key=True, editable=False)

class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) #null is default=False and is required
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True) #for a bigger field, allows null(for db)/blank(for Django get/post)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='default.jpg')
    demo_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    source_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True) #can be blank in db
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True) #quotes will ref other class after this one 
    vote_total = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    vote_ratio = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #generate when model instance is created
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Foreign key fields do not match with another field in another model. it matches with the model itself.Let's say you want to assign a profile with the name 'victor' to new project model object, it would go like this:

```
from app_name.model import Project, Profile

profile1=Profile.objects.filter(name='victor').first()
new_project=Project(title='project 1',demolink='demo link',owner=profile1)
```

here, we assigned a user object to the owner property of the project and not a field.

The `Profile.User` field isn't necessary.
if you want to create a `customUser`, i suggest you should look that up or you'll be giving yourself many problems with authentication. You'll have to create a model manager for it after which you can begin to customise. It should look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given username and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_('The Username must be set'))
        user = self.model(username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given username and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)

class Profile(AbstractUser):

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    short_intro = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        null=True, blank=True, upload_to='profiles/', default='profiles/user-default.png')
    social_github = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_youtube = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    social_website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, 
                        primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: I'm still confused. How does the Project.owner field know to match with Profile.user and not Profile.name?

Comment: i have edited my answer. i hope its clear enough

Comment: I appreciate the response and I'll upvote the answer in case it is helpful to others. I must still have a few legos missing in my understanding of django models as I still don't understand how this works. In SQL, you have to specify the table and field when assigning a foreign key. But django just assigns other models... i don't get it because how does the second table use on_delete=models.CASCADE to delete the original table entry if it doesn't know what field to match to.

Comment: `on_delete=models.CASCADE` simply means to delete the model you are relating to another model when the other model has been deleted. because in some fields, you might not specify `null=True`, so that field cannot be nullified. Django will be left with a space in the database which isn't valid because it cannot be nullified. when you delete the other model, it becomes null because it cannot cannot find the other model but it can't really change the value to null because you didn't allow that. if you want to use `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`, you must also specify `null=True` for that field

Answer (score 2):

**The field which has primary key** is referenced by default if only setting a model name to **"models.ForeignKey()"** as mentioned in [**ForeignKey.to_field**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field):

> **ForeignKey.to_field**
>
> ...
> By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object.
> ...

This is the full explanation of [**ForeignKey.to_field**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field):

> **ForeignKey.to_field**
>
> The field on the related object that the relation
> is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object.
> If you reference a different field, that field must have unique=True.

Comment: this feels like the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Viq. I have solved my confusion now. The ForeignKey specifies a model but it ***always*** connects to that model's Primary Key which is why I don't have to specify Project.title or Project.id. Then when the Review model with the ForeignKey is output it calls the Project model's str method which lists out the title. I didn't realize the str method was being called.

I didn't include the str method in my code example because i didn't think that it had anything to do with my issue but I now understand that the str method is why I am seeing Project.title instead of Project.id.

> def **str**(self): return self.title

This is the piece of the puzzle i was missing.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

ForeignKey.to_field
The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object. If you reference a different field, that field must have unique=True.